# Replicate "Custom Tables" comparison in R

Tags: r, spss

I use SPSS everyday but have really been trying to learn R.  The major thing that is holding me back is my need to easily generate tables, banners, and cross-tabs for the market research that I do.  I love the Custom Tables option in SPSS and am looking for advice on how to replicate it with R.

I believe R has a ton of advantages over SPSS, one of which is the ability to integrate with LaTeX for reproducible reports.  SPSS is great for quick exploration (point and click), but leaves alot to be desired when taking the results and packaging it to an acceptable deliverable for clients, etc. That said, R is so powerful, I feel like I could do everything I need in it if I could only do my banners/crosstabs the way I need them.

In short, what are my options to generate report-worthy tables similar to what I have below? I am copying the SPSS syntax command and the output for reference.

```
CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=age educ paeduc maeduc speduc prestg80 happy 
    DISPLAY=DEFAULT 
  /TABLE age [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] + educ [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] + paeduc [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] + maeduc [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] + speduc [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] + prestg80 [MEAN F40.3, VALIDN COMMA40.0] BY happy 
  /SLABELS POSITION=ROW 
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=happy ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES POSITION=AFTER MISSING=EXCLUDE 
  /SIGTEST TYPE=CHISQUARE ALPHA=0.05 INCLUDEMRSETS=YES CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE 
  /COMPARETEST TYPE=MEAN ALPHA=0.05 ADJUST=BONFERRONI ORIGIN=COLUMN INCLUDEMRSETS=YES CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE MEANSVARIANCE=ALLCATS MERGE=NO 
  /COMPARETEST TYPE=PROP ALPHA=0.05 ADJUST=BONFERRONI ORIGIN=COLUMN INCLUDEMRSETS=YES CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE MERGE=NO.
```

I attached a picture of what the output looks like.  I am particuarly interested in the ability to have multiple variables in the rows/columns and like the flexibility to nest them if I need to.  In the image, I have a few continuous variables cut by a categorical variable in the column with the summary statistics placed in the rows. As an aside, I also really like the feature of quick column mean comparisons -- but figure in can quickly access them in R for conditional crosstab generation.

Comment: Is there any update on this matter? This was asked in 2010 and I wonder what's the situation now. I'm really missing this possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explore a "tabular" function from the ["tables"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) package. I think it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is not currently easy in R.  You are likely to have to string together multiple functions from multiple packages to get output like this.

Comment: Thanks Hadley.  I am getting that impression, which is a huge bummer.  That said, your packages are fantastic!

Comment: Hadley, how about now (2013)? Is it still complicated?

Comment: @fioghual You may want to look at http://www.eoda.de/index.php/en/tableR.html or http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the package psych, and it is pretty good at producing tables for summary statistics broken down by variables.  it doesn't format as nice as say stata.  I think you can output it into a text file and then format it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

There were several presentations on this topic at useR 2010, so you may see more packages out soon that attempt to address this.

Answer (score 0):

See [xtable](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/xtable/html/xtable.html) package for some table exporting to LaTeX and HTML. There may be other packages, though. [This](http://pj.freefaculty.org/stat/ps706/table-from-R.pdf) looks promising as well. Have you heard of Sweave?

Comment: I have - I figure once I figure out a way to create summary tables/banners/cross tabs the way I need them, it will be easy to automate my reports using Sweave.  That said, the first hurdle is creating the tables.......

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble many times with un-user-friendly output of R... The only solution I found was writing my own function and I'm happy to share it with you here:

The following function returns for all factor variables in a data.frame the frequency or the percentage (calc="perc") for each level of the factor variable "variable".

The most important thing may be that the output is a simple user friendly data.frame. So it is no problem to export the results an work with it in any way you want.

I realize that there is much potential for further improvements, i.e. add a possibility for selecting row vs. column percentage calculation, etc. It's a work-in-progress status, but gets the job done.

```
contitable <- function( survey_data, variable, calc="freq" ){    

  # Check which variables are not given as factor    
  # and exlude them from the given data.frame    
 survey_data_factor_test <- as.logical( sapply( Survey, FUN=is.factor) )    
  survey_data <- subset( survey_data, select=which( survey_data_factor_test ) )    

  # Inform the user about deleted variables    
  # is that proper use of printing to console during a function call??    
  # for now it worksjust fine...    
  flush.console()        
  writeLines( paste( "\n ", sum( !survey_data_factor_test, na.rm=TRUE),
            "non-factor variable(s) were excluded\n" ) )

  variable_levels <- levels(survey_data[ , variable ])    
  variable_levels_length <- length( variable_levels )    

  # Initializing the data.frame which will gather the results    
  result <- data.frame( "Variable", "Levels", t(rep( 1, each=variable_levels_length ) ) )    
  result_column_names <- paste( variable, variable_levels, sep="." )    
  names(result) <- c("Variable", "Levels", result_column_names )    

  for(column in 1:length( names(survey_data) ) ){       

      column_levels_length <- length( levels( survey_data[ , column ] ) )
      result_block <- as.data.frame( rep( names(survey_data)[column], each=column_levels_length ) )
      result_block <- cbind( result_block, as.data.frame( levels( survey_data[,column] ) ) )
      names(result_block) <- c( "Variable", "Levels" )

      results <- table( survey_data[ , column ], survey_data[ , variable ] )

      if( calc=="perc" ){ 
        results <- apply( results, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x){ x/sum(x) }) 
        results <- round( results*100, 1 )
      }

      results <- unclass(results)
      results <- as.data.frame( results )
      names( results ) <- result_column_names
      rownames(results) <- NULL

      result_block <- cbind( result_block, results) 
      result <- rbind( result, result_block ) 
}    
result <- result[-1,]        
return( result )    
}
```